# How did the IP address of destination jump from DNS in L5 to IP header in L3?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

DNS is in L5. My browser is in L5. My browser in L5 asks DNS in L5 what is the IP address for google.com. How did the IP address of destination jumped from DNS in L5 to IP header in L3. L5 header does not carry the IP address of destination. L4 header does not carry the IP address of destination. L3 header needs the IP of destination in Bits 128-159.
Just clarification about my layer numbering. I use Kurose numbering. L5=application, L4=transport, L3=network, L2=data/link, L1= physical layer.

Comment: Your browser passed the IP address to the `connect()` call, which gave it to the kernel, which gave it to the TCP layer, which gave it to the IP layer.

Comment: Thanks 207421.
Two follow ups if I may.
(a)
From what you are saying it seems there is not pure layered system which would require that only  L(k-1)  to L(k) to L(k+1) and no other ways. 
(b)
Any real reason TCP layer  gets the IP from the kernel. As opposed the IP layer gets the IP from the kernel. I see IP layer needs the IP info but do not see TCP layer header showing that IP info.
Is there maybe some reason why TCP layer needs the IP info?
And if TCP layer needs it, why Internet ppl did not put IP info into the TCP header which gets passed to IP layer.

Comment: Ok replace my (b) question above with this question. Clearly TCP/L4 needs IP address for congestion control. Then the question can be asked, why the Internet ppl did not put the IP address into the L4 header, since L4 has it, and L3 needs it. But the IP of destination is not inside the L4 header.

Comment: 1. There are no layering violations in my comment, but you are correct that such pure layering doesn't exist in the real world. 2. I've answered that. connect() gives it to the kernel, and the kernel gives it to TCP, and so on. The TCP layer needs the IP information to identify sockets. As the IP address is already in the IP packet it would be redundant to put it imto the TCP segment. NB 'L5' doesn't really exist. It just means everything above the TCP/IP stack.

Comment: "_Then the question can be asked, why the Internet ppl did not put the IP address into the L4 header, since L4 has it, and L3 needs it. But the IP of destination is not inside the L4 header._" It really is in some transport protocol headers. For example, both TCP and UDP need it for the pseudo header used in calculating the CRC values for those protocols.

Comment: Well it 'really' isn't part of the TCP header, but it is *considered* part of the TCP header for checksum purposes. @RonMaupin

Comment: Thanks everyone. It helped to clarify. I would like to accept answer by user207421 but I cant find how to do it. Maybe because of my low reputation. I can not see any grey checkmark to select.